# Where Are the JavaDocs for Room?

Tags: android, android-room, android-architecture-components

Room sounds interesting, but I cannot find any of the classes in [the Android Developer site's JavaDocs](https://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html), as they do not show up when searching. Are JavaDocs available for Room?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The search problem will be fixed eventually, I hope.

However, you can also access the JavaDocs more directly. In the Reference area, above the package tree, you will find a pair of drop-down lists:

[image: Reference Drop-Down Lists]

The one showing "Android Platform" can be switched to "Architecture Components", which brings up [the classes for all the Architecture Components](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/classes.html), including Room:

[image: Reference for Architecture Components]

Answer (score 0):

Here're what I found:

[Docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html)

[Reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/package-summary.html)